# Find Middle points(Computational geometry c++)

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

This program should read for input an integer N then the x and y coordinates of the N points
and return the number of points that are the middle points of any two other points in the set.
First the program stores the points in an array then we loop throgh the points and calculate the distance between points[i] and every other point. We sort the points according to that distance then if we find that any two points have the same distance we check if point[i] is aligned with them if it is the case we store point[i] in the middles list.
We then get rid of doubles in the list and return the size of the list.
I submitted my solution and it doesn't work for all the cases. Please help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int distance;
};
bool PointSort(Point a,Point b);
bool colinear(Point a,Point b,Point c);
bool same_point (Point first, Point second);
int main()
{
    list<Point> middles;
    int N;scanf("%d", &N);
    Point points[N];
    Point points2[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {   scanf("%d", &points[i].x);
        scanf("%d", &points[i].y);
        points2[i].x=points[i].x;
        points2[i].y=points[i].y;

    }
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
         for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
         {
            points2[j]=points[j];
         }
         for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
         {

            points2[j].distance=(points[i].x-points2[j].x)*(points[i].x-    points2[j].x)+(points[i].y-points2[j].y)*(points[i].y-points2[j].y);

         }
         sort(points2,points2+N,&PointSort);
         for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
         {

            int k=j+1;
            while(points2[j].distance==points2[k].distance)
            {

                 bool coli=colinear(points[i],points2[j],points2[k]);
                 if(coli){middles.push_back(points2[i]);}
                 k++;
            }
         }
     }
    middles.unique(same_point);
    cout<<middles.size();


}
bool PointSort(Point a,Point b)
{
    return a.distance<b.distance;
}
bool colinear(Point a,Point b,Point c)
{
    return (a.x*(b.y-c.y)+b.x*(c.y-a.y)+c.x*(a.y-b.y))/2.0==0.0;
} 
bool same_point (Point first, Point second)
{ return (first.x==second.x && first.y==second.y) ; }
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise questions like this come across as "my code isn't working, here's a huge code dump, debug it for me!"

Comment: `I submitted my solution and it doesn't work for all the cases.` Those test cases should be in the question. Secondly, if you're using C++, please consider using `std::cin` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. That's a lot of code. Please see a [__Minimal__, __Complete__, and __Verifiable__ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [__Short__, __Self Contained__, Correct (__Compilable__) example](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to calculate distances to check if something is the midpoint. The coordinates of the midpoint between A and B is M=(A+B)/2. Or, to keep everything as an integer, A+B=2M where M is the midpoint. Here's a pseudocode solution for the problem:

```
for ( A=0; A<N-1; A++ ) {
    for ( B=A+1; B<N; B++ ) {
        M2 = A+B;
        for ( C=0; C<N; C++ ) {
            if ( C*2 == M2 ) {
               // C is the midpoint of A and B
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but your solution runs in O(n3) which is too slow so I need a O(n2) solution.

Comment: "solve the problem for you in O(n2)" wasn't what you asked, so I think this is a good answer.  You solution also looks like O(n3) to me.  Google "spatial partitioning" to better it.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following potential problems with your code:

1. Your code computes the distance squared (not the distance as stated) between pairs of points.  Since the calculation is being done using integer arithmetic, there's a chance of arithmetic overflow.
2. Your code removes all midpoints found with duplicated x and y coordinates.  But, is this what the problem statement requires?  If duplicate points *actually appear in the input stream*, and happen to be midpoints of some other points, should the second and all subsequent duplicates be ignored?  Also, if a point is duplicated three (or more) times in the input stream, how many midpoints does that count as?  You should carefully check the problem statement to see how duplicates in the input stream should be counted and follow the requirements precisely.
3. Your check for collinearity looks wrong.  You appear to be trying to take a 2d cross of `(points[i] - points2[j])` with `(points[i] - points2[k])`, but this is not the correct way to do it.   Here is how to take a 2d cross:

   ```
   int cross2d(Point a, Point mid, Point c)
   {
       // Take the 2d cross product (a - mid) X (c - mid).
       // 2d cross = (u.x * v.y - u.y * v.x) where u = (a-mid) and v=(c - mid)
       int cross = (a.x - mid.x) * (c.y - mid.y) - (a.y - mid.y) * (c.x - mid.x);
       return cross;
   }

   bool collinear(Point a, Point mid, Point c)
   {
       // Check for the points being collinear (or degenerate, i.e. return true if a == mid or mid == c).
       return cross2d(a, mid, c) == 0;
   }
   ```

   Again, integer overflow is a potential problem for point triplets with large coordinates that are nearly perpendicular.  And if you were not trying to take a 2d cross, what were you trying to do?
4. You're trying create an O(n-squared) algorithm by sorting the points by distance from some prospective midpoint.  That's creditable, but since your code isn't working I would start by creating a naive O(n-cubed) algorithm that solves the problem straightforwardly.  Then you can use that to unit-test your improved n-squared algorithm.
5. Adding some spacing into your mathematical expressions makes them easier to read.

So, to start you off, here's the naive n-cubed algorithm.  Note that I am preserving duplicates in the input stream while avoiding double-counting of points that are midpoints of multiple pairs of points:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int id;
};

bool is_middle(Point a, Point middle, Point c);
bool same_point_id(Point first, Point second);

int main()
{
    list<Point> middles;
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437597/find-middle-pointscomputational-geometry-c
    // This program should read for input an integer N then the x and y coordinates of the N points 
    // and return the number of points that are the middle points of any two other points in the set. 

    Point *points = new Point[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {   
        scanf("%d", &points[i].x);
        scanf("%d", &points[i].y);
        points[i].id = i;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<N-2; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<N-1; j++)
        {
            for(int k=j+1; k<N; k++)
            {
                // Check the problem requirement to determine how to count sets of three identical points in the input stream.
                if (is_middle(points[i], points[j], points[k]))
                    middles.push_back(points[j]);
                if (is_middle(points[j], points[k], points[i]))
                    middles.push_back(points[k]);
                if (is_middle(points[k], points[i], points[j]))
                    middles.push_back(points[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Prevent the same input point from being counted multiple times.
    middles.unique(same_point_id);
    cout<<middles.size();

    delete [] points;
}

bool is_middle(Point a, Point mid, Point c)
{
    if (a.x - c.x != 2*(a.x - mid.x))
        return false;
    if (a.y - c.y != 2*(a.y - mid.y))
        return false;
    return true;
}

bool same_point_id(Point first, Point second)
{ 
    return (first.id==second.id); 
}
```

**Update:** If you do need an n-squared algorithm then sorting potential endpoints by distance squared from the midpoint isn't a bad idea.  If you want to avoid potential arithmetic overflows, you can do calculate the distance squared in 64bit [long long ints](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types):

```
long long distance_squared(Point a, Point b)
{
    long long dx = ((long long)a.x - (long long)b.x);
    long long dy = ((long long)a.y - (long long)b.y);
    return dx*dx + dy*dy;
}
```

On most platforms these will have more bits than a regular int -- and certainly not fewer.

Comment: scanf in C++ after including iostream ??

Comment: @Emilio Garavaglia - I preserved the original poster's input code rather than rewriting it.  c++ isn't my primary language anyway and I was trying to help fix the geometry, not the coding style.  (I don't think that's what is causing the problem, do you?)

Comment: Of course. I was trying to go further: when a number of not used includes are there, the impression is that the OP is not in trouble with just geometry, but is also spitting code randomly attempting to get a right result by attempts. It's not just style, but also revealing a missing "design". I was not asking to "correct" the answer, but stimulate a thinking about it to the OP.

Comment: @Marouene Sfar Gandoura - answer updated with suggestion to avoid overflows.

Comment: @dbc I actually have a similar problem, given a list of points count each that are middle of two points in list, every iteration getting a new x y, so n times list, then n squared to compute every middle and check if it's in list, mind detailing the approach to get a n squared solution? thanks in advance

Comment: @adaba - this answer is over 6 years old and never upvoted, so you should probably just ask another question.